# Is it possible to save the console's output of a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am running a series of operations inside a Jupyter notebook. Some of those operations, print their results on the console pane which when executed inside a notebook environment, the results show up in the Jupyter notebook's console window. I need to save those logs as well.
Is there a way that I can save that console's content ?
Or even better, Is there a way that I can altogether make any messages that are sent to console, being saved/piped/redirected to a file instead ?

Please note that, I myself do print some messages inside notebook, and I don't want to save those messages to the file. I specifically want a third application/library which prints its messages on a console, get saved/redirected to a file.

Therefore simply doing :
 `sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')`

is not a viable choice, because it saves the print messages inside the notebook and not the ones displayed on the console.

Comment: Have you tried the `capture` magic? http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture

Comment: @nitind: Thanks alot, is there an example showing how this should be use?